# Get intersection between two lists

Tags: python, list, intersect

I want to intersect two lists (with NOT), and return the elements of list A that are not present in list B.

example:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> b = [1,3,5,6]
>>> list(set(a) ????? set(b))
[2, 4]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for the set difference; the `-` operator will do that for you:

```
list(set(a) - set(b))
```

If you use the [`set.difference()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.difference) the second operand does not need to be a set, it can be any iterable:

```
list(set(a).difference(b))
```

Demo:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> b = [1,3,5,6]
>>> list(set(a).difference(b))
[2, 4]
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
>>> list(set(a) - set(b))
[2, 4]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [1,3,5,6]
print list(set(a) - set(b))
```